# how to reduce size of generated gitbook website?

Tags: gitbook

I have project of documentation in gitbook with about of 1000 pages. Result of website generation is set of html files in common size 300 MB. There are 2 causes of such result:

1) All pages listed in SUMMARY.md and as result all generated static htmls has this large menu in 1000 links. The menu is not fully shown thanks to plugin which hides subchapters, but in any case whole menu is inside each html page. If to remove a page link from the SUMMARY.md, the associated html file doesn't generates. Is where any method to generate website with reduce menu (in this case access to subchapters pages will be provided from content of chapters pages)?

2) Big part of the content is not english text, and it translates in sequence of 7-chars codes (like this &#x0123), how to keep native 1-char symbol?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your second issue, but it sounds like you can segment the menu as you wish, judging from the theming documentation: https://toolchain.gitbook.com/templating/variables.html